# Does automatic hyperparemeter tuning on Matlab stop on its own?

Tags: performance, matlab, iteration, svm, hyperparameters

I'm tuning hyperparameters automatically using fitrsvm and my  last 6 iterations have said 'accept' and not 'best'. I am wondering if I am supposed to stop the execution manually or if Matlab will do it on its own.

```
Mdl = fitrsvm (X_train, Y_train, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf',...
    'OptimizeHyperparameters', 'auto',...
    'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions', struct('AcquisitionFunctionName',...
    'expected-improvement-plus','ShowPlots', true));
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Given the [docs](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrsvm.html) show similar results, I presume that's normal. Otherwise this is more of a question for [stats.se] than for here, given it's about SVM theory, rather than an actual programming problem.

Comment: THank you, I wil post my question there! It looks normal but I am wondering when it's gonna stop because to me it looks like it's reached convergence already but it is still running and my laptop is overheating